# Unmarshal JSON to Map/List of Strings

Tags: json, apache-camel

I would like to unmarshal a Json to a Map/List of Strings (eg Map>...)

Here is my input:

```
{"pointsOfSale": 
{"pointOfSale":[ 
{"href":"\/pointsOfSale\/UUID.0abc2aca-7930-4c9e-9f38-8af3d0692e04", 
"model":{"href":"\/models\/modelePointOfSale", 
"modelType":{"href":"\/modelTypes\/pointOfSale"}}, 
"source":{"href":"\/sources\/TEST"}, 
"attribute":[ 
{"code":"pointOfSalePhysical","value":true}, 
{"code":"mail","value":"Mail1"}, 
{"code":"adresse","value":"address1"}]}, 
{"href":"\/pointsOfSale\/UUID.a12e7adf-652a-4197-91bf-d4785e43f09f", 
"model":{"href":"\/models\/modelePointOfSale", 
"modelType":{"href":"\/modelTypes\/pointOfSale"}}, 
"source":{"href":"\/sources\/Wikeo"}, 
"attribute":[ 
{"code":"pointOfSalePhysical","value":false}, 
{"code":"mail","value":"Mail1"}, 
{"code":"adresseMateriau","value":"Material address1"}]} 
}}
```

I would like to be able to do "something" like this after unmarshaling:

```
myJsonMapped.get("pointsOfSale").get("pointOfSale").get(0).get("source").get("href").equals("\/sources\/TEST") == true
```

For instance, with Gson we can do this kind of decoding:

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);
```

I know I can do this with a simple bean or processor etc...

I just want to know of I can do this more efficiently with a native JSON camel component config

EDIT: I tried different thing already like : 
unmarshal().json()... 
or 
unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, Map.class).. 
etc... 
without succes :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this with jackson.

```
<dataFormats>
  <json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
</dataFormats>

...

<route>
  <from uri="direct:test"/>
  <unmarshal ref="jack"/>
  <process ref="something"/>
</route>
```

Or in java with gson:

```
 from("foo:bar")
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson,Map.class)
    .to("foo:baz");
```

If you're not getting it to work, please state error and so fourth.